# phpmyadmin and 1MB post data

Tags: phpmyadmin, post

In php.ini I have set php to allow 7MB POST data size. But when I used phpmyadmin to save 1MB data of text into a field, it just listed all the record from the parent table and did nothing to the record which supposed to be changed after I pressed the "save" button.

Is this a limit of phpmyadmin? What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Is the field of type LONGTEXT? Anything less and MySQL would not store it.

Comment: You also might just be running into an execution timeout. That's a lot of data to send all at once and the server could just be killing the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the MySQL text field size limits

TINYTEXT    256 bytes

TEXT            65,535 bytes    ~64kb

MEDIUMTEXT  16,777,215 bytes    ~16MB

LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB

Comment: I don't really know whether this is the correct answer or not. I ended up saving the query into a file and used SOURCE command from the command line to update the field for me, instead of using phpmyadmin. Anyway, thanks for that information.